# Creating an array, says its an object? (S3)

Tags: php, amazon-s3

I create an array like so:

```
private $commands = [];
```

I then add to this array:

```
$this->commands[] = $this->s3->getCommand('PutObject', [
        'Bucket' => xxx,
        'Key' => xxx,
        'Body' => xxx,
        'ContentType' => xxx,
        'ACL' => 'public-read'
    ]);
```

But when I try to use the array:

```
$pool = $this->s3->commandPool($this->s3, $this->commands);
```

I get the error:

```
Argument 2 passed to Aws\AwsClient::getCommand() must be of the type array, object given,
```

It's complaining about an object, and requiring an array.

Am I creating the array wrong?

(I am using php 5.4 so array[] is fine)

Comment: The error is about getCommand method, not commandPool. Could you dump the class name of $this->s3?

Comment: That is: $this->s3 = AWS::createClient('s3'); Im using a laravel facade: https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php-laravel

Comment: This method can return objects of different classes. Please do dd(get_class($this->s3);

Comment: dd is: "Aws\S3\S3Client"

Comment: Weird, I can see that you're passing array to getCommand. Are you sure this is the line that causes the error? Don't you call getCommand somewhere else? You should have the filename and line number in the error message.

Comment: get command is not used elsewhere. The error occurs: ErrorException in AwsClient.php line 211 which is in /vendor/aws/aws-sdk-php/src/AwsClient.php

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83435/discussion-between-jedrzej-kurylo-and-panthro).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using commandPool incorrectly. There is no such method and when you call an undefined method AwsClient assumes you're trying to send a command and calls getCommand() internally - that's why you're getting the error.

The correct way to do so is:

```
//at the top of your file
use Aws\CommandPool;

//and then
$pool = new CommandPool($this->s3, $this->commands);
```